# Spread operator in yarn script

Tags: node.js, cypress, yarnpkg

When I launch `yarn cypress run` I got an error:

```
/node_modules/log-symbols/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js:106
    ...styles,
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/log-symbols/index.js:2:15)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

how can I enable spread operator in yarn/node environment?

Comment: Could you share your node version? `node -v`

Comment: Yes, its 12.16.1

Comment: Hi, can we see the whole context of the code, please?